# regex error in django url

Tags: python, regex, django, url, parameters

My django url is not working, I get a ReverseMatch error:

```
Reverse for 'activation_mail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'activation_key': '1c38a44d216a51c26e65d789a3d8af2677cebebd', u'email': u'myemail@gmail.com', u'site_url': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'accounts/mails/(P<activation_key>[0-9a-zA-Z]{40})/(P<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)/(P<site_url>.*)/$']
```

The error happens when a user registers to the website. After entering a captcha code, the error occurs when trying to send a confirmation email to the user address.

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^mails/(P<activation_key>[0-9a-zA-Z]{40})/(P<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)/(P<site_url>.*)/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='accounts/mails/activation_email.html'), name='activation_mail'),
)
```

The mail is sent from the view that triggers the following function in the model...

**models.py:**

```
  class SignupProfile(models.Model):
    objects = SignupManager()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True,
                             verbose_name=_("utilisateur"))
    activation_key = models.CharField(_("clef d'activation"), max_length=40)

    def send_activation_email(self, request):
        activation_url = reverse(
            'accounts:activation',
            kwargs={'activation_key': self.activation_key})

        ctx = Context({'site_url': settings.SITE_URL,
                       'activation_key': self.activation_key,
                       'email': self.user.email})

        html_tpl = get_template('accounts/mails/activation_email.html')
        html_content = html_tpl.render(ctx)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content,
                                     settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                                     [self.user.email])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
        msg.send()
```

The error happens in the template used for the mail...

**index.html:**

```
            <a href="{% url 'accounts:activation_mail' activation_key=activation_key email=email site_url=site_url %}" target="_blank">View this email in your browser</a>
```

I have used http://pythex.org/, the regex works.
[image]
What's the error?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the set up: the single function in `views.py` isn't a view, it's logic to send email. Is that the entirety of your main `urls.py` file? It should be setting up a `urlpatterns` variable to hold those urls. It's not possible to answer completely without seeing the values you are using for the keyword variables.

Comment: I just edited my post with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *named group* [syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) is not correct. It should start with `?`:

```
^mails/(?P<activation_key>[0-9a-zA-Z]{40})/(?P<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)/(?P<site_url>.*)/$
    HERE^                               HERE^                                                      HERE^
```

---

As a side note, I also think the last wildcard match should be *non-greedy* (not sure if this matters):

```
(?P<site_url>.*?)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this rule, because the name group must start with *?*

```
    r'^mails/(?P<activation_key>[0-9a-zA-Z]{40})/(?P<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)/(?P<site_url>.*)/$'
```